# How to delete a table with SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm just trying to figure out something here. I'm looking into SQL injection, and I can't seem to delete this table no matter how much I try to, and I was wondering if maybe it just can't be done -
may I have some examples of how this table can be deleted?

```
<?php

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$cxn = mysqli_connect($a,$b,$c,$d);
if ($cxn) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE logins = '{$username}';";
// tried sending: '; DROP TABLE members".' doesn't work...
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql)
if (!$result) { echo 'Couldn\'t be done!'; } else { echo 'Query completed!'; }

}

?>
```

So, how would I delete table members using SQL injection - or is it web-safe? Thanks.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do a delete statement with the SELECT query.

Comment: That may not be your issue but this code has a syntax error : `echo 'Couldn't be done!';`, you shoud escape the second quote.

Comment: `$username` = `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members)` would be successful.

Comment: My program just searches for that statement as a whole, as in: $username = '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members)', which isn't found...Maybe '; (SELECT COUNT FROM MEMBERS)".' ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLi doesn't allow multi-stacked queries, unless you're using [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query), so `DELETE`-ing or `DROP`-ping wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

How ever, this code is still very insecure.

lets say $username getst the value

```
$username = "' or id > '1"
```

it would transfer into

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE logins = '' or id > '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fatal misunderstanding.

SQL injection **is not equal** to dropping a table. The latter action is just an example, quite vivid, but not too feasible in read circumstances. But **injections aren't limited to just dropping tables!**

So, even if this particular kind of injection isn't possible in your particular case, it doesn't make your code "web-safe"!

Instead of caring of numerous particular ways to exploit of injection, you have to mitigate all injections at once. By means of using **prepared statements**